# Separate blocks in region

Tags: 8, blocks, theming

I have a Footer region defined for my theme, and it has two blocks in it.

I have a `region--footer.html.twig` file and both blocks are rendered with `{{ content }}`.

The issue is, I need to wrap both blocks in some containers, and then each in separate containers, something like this:

```
<div>

  <div>
    {{ block_1 }}
  </div>

  <div>
    {{ block_2 }}
  </div>

</div>
```

How do I reference the blocks individually?

One of the blocks was custom and is some basic HTML, I can't seem to find a machine name for it, so I can't even try `{{ content.my_custom_block }}`

Comment: The region content is already rendered, so it's better to put the div in the block template.

Comment: Lets just say I still want to try this approach, is there a way?

Comment: The content is already rendered (html), so unless you want to perform some awful string replacements, or parse the html into something like a DOMDocument and manipulate it that way, no